# If 2 phrase's from sheet 1 match in sheet2 then copy that row to sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I've bumped into a problem of catching from where to start this code.

I have 1 master data ( sheet1 ) sheet and uploaded sheet ( sheet 2 ).

Flow what need's to be done :

Sheet1 has 2 specific words ( TREE and WOOD ) if these words match in Sheet2 between 2 cells then copy that row from A2 till R2 to the last row in that sheet.

Adding NEW.

So I wrote a code that finds specific value in column F if it matches then it will copy and paste the row to other sheet.

I've bumped into a problem where I have error when i try to squeeze Range to copy from A:O columns.

Does anyone has in mind where is my mistake?

```
Sub Copyrow()

Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet


Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterDATA")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MainData")

j = 1
For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F20000")
    If c = "PMC" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).copy ' I'm trying to squeeze .Range before .Rows
       Target.Rows(j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
             Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c

With Range("H1:H5000")
.NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I will add my code soon here!

Comment: Posted my code above if someone can find a problem why .range doesn't work that would be wonderful . In the mean time i'm also searching what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by `squeeze Range`? Do you mean something like `Source.Range("A" & c.Row, "O" & c.Row).Copy`?

Comment: I have a main data sheet. In that sheet i have formulas that start from column P . When it copies and paste's it cut all of them. So i this case I need that When copying from Master data it would have a Range between A and O , same when paste.

Comment: `Source.Range("A" & c.Row, "O" & c.Row).Copy` will only copy that row from column A to O. Just make sure you paste in the same range `Target.Range("A" & j, "O" & j).PasteSpecial`

Comment: Yes! It worked :D .

Comment: Posted it as an answer so you can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

`Source.Range("A" & c.Row, "O" & c.Row).Copy` will only copy that row from column A to O.

Just make sure you paste in the same range `Target.Range("A" & j, "O" & j).PasteSpecial`.